# How to pass environment variables (runtime variables) to a lambda function from an EventBridge rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I have two event bridge rules pointing to a lambda function with two different aliases (say dev & prod). How do I send runtime arguments from EventBridge to respective lambda alias?
If that's not possible, how to set environment variable (or runtime arguments) for a specific lambda alias?

Currently, it is only possible to add them globally (applicable to all aliases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [input transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-input-transformer-tutorial.html). Each rule will have its input transformer which you write. This can including adding new parameters to the event, indicating `dev` or `prod` environments.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm also thinking about a simpler approach where I specify the `target input` as a constant JSON and pass something like `{ "env" : "dev" }`  in the eventbridge target configuration.

Comment: @RahulRaj I think this will overwrite your original event. But if its not important, then `target input` is easier to use.

Comment: got it, Thanks for the extended help :)